# How to generate WSDL file for SOAP Based web Service?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have been recently working on a java project using spring to create few additional API's. The original web service already exist and so its wsdl file. Now i am suppose to add more features.

For this project, first .xsd request and response files are created and then from X2J xml files are auto generated to java files. Using these files as fields i also create the new API. Now i need to add these new API in exisiting wsdl. The existing wsdl is too long and so is there any way i can generate wsdl for new and old API .

```
  web.xml file 

     <!-- Servlet to expose webservices -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>messageDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>messageDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>messageDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


    messageDispatcher-servlet.xml file


     <!-- Add supported requests here to define them in the WSDL -->
        <bean id="schemaCollection" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
     <value>classpath:xmlbind/zzzzRQ.xsd</value>
                    <value>classpath:xmlbind/zzzzRS.xsd</value>
                    <value>classpath:xmlbind/yyyyRQ.xsd</value>
                    <value>classpath:xmlbind/yyyyRS.xsd</value>


    <!-- CONFIGURE WSDL -->
    <bean id="XXXX" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
            <property name="schemaCollection" ref="schemaCollection"/>
            <property name="portTypeName" value="ACVWS_"/>
            <property name="locationUri" value="/services"/>
            <property name="requestSuffix" value="RQ"/>
            <property name="responseSuffix" value="RS"/>
        </bean>

    </bean>
        <bean id="xxxx_v1_0" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
            <property name="wsdl" value="classpath:/wsdl/xxxx_v1_0.wsdl"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="xxxx_v2_0" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
            <property name="wsdl" value="classpath:/wsdl/xxxx_v2_0.wsdl"></property>
        </bean>
```

Comment: The existing code has not used annotation based way to define endpoints too